# NodeJs __dirname does not return expected result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using nodejs and __dirname is not returning the expected result. For index.js, I am expecting __dirname to include /js in the end like fetch.js.

index.js:

```
console.log(__dirname) //C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projects\Electron\project\app
```

fetch.js:

```
console.log(__dirname) //C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projects\Electron\project\app\js
```

My project structure:

```
/project
    /.git
    /app
        /css
            index.css
        /js
            index.js
            key.js
            fetch.js
        index.html
    /node_modules
    /test
        ...
    main.js
```

Comment: Need a bit more to go on here...

Comment: Since it looks like you're doing an Electron project, is `index.js` your main process and `fetch.js` is running in your renderer process?

Comment: My main process is main.js which is under /project. Sorry I left it out after the ellipsis. I'm running console.log(__dirname) on the files themselves.

Comment: Is this maybe what's going on? https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3204

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how fetch.js shows js which is in the same directory. 
But you can use concatenate function. 
console.log(__dirname || '\js')